# Creating a method

Tags: c#

```
protected void calculateRateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //declare variables and retrieve user inputs
    int nbPeopleInt;
    string roomTypeString;
    int nbNightsInt;

    nbNightsInt = int.Parse(nbNightsTextBox.Text);
    nbPeopleInt = int.Parse(nbPeopleDropDownList.Text);
    roomTypeString = roomTypeDropDownList.Text;

    int totalFareInt = calculateRoomBooking(roomTypeString, nbPeopleInt, nbNightsInt);
}

private int calculateRoomBooking(string RoomType, int nbNights, int nbPeople)
{

    int totalFareInt = 0;
    int dailyRateInt = 0;

    // set daily rate based on selected room type
    switch (RoomType)
    {
        case "Standard":
            dailyRateInt = 100;
            break;
        case "Superior":
            dailyRateInt = 150;
            break;
        case "Luxury":
            dailyRateInt = 175;
            break;
    }

    // calculation of booking rate
    totalFareInt = dailyRateInt * nbNightsInt + 10 * (nbPeopleInt - 1) * nbNightsInt;

    // display booking rate
    totalRateTextBox.Text = totalFareInt.ToString();
}

protected void roomDetailsButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    // go to room details page
    Response.Redirect("RoomDetails.aspx");
}
```

however, it always say that dailyRateInt, nbNightsInt, nbPeopleInt is not defined with this line:

```
totalFareInt = dailyRateInt * nbNightsInt + 10 * (nbPeopleInt - 1) * nbNightsInt;
```

But I did define them above as you guys can see

please helps

Comment: `nbNightsInt` and `nbPeopleInt` are defined in one method and then you try to use them in another. You should be using the method's parameters inside the method, not the names of the variables you pass in elsewhere.

Comment: the variables arent defined in the method you are trying to use them in.  You need to consider scope

Comment: Please go through the fundamentals of scope. nbPeopleInt is local for calculateRateButton_Click but not for calculateRoomBooking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `nbPeopleInt` is local variable for `calculateRateButton_Click` and it used outside the scope of the method. Hence you are getting the issue.

You may probably define `nbPeopleInt`, `roomTypeString` and `nbNightsInt` outside the `calculateRateButton_Click` method

You may probably want to do this:-

```
private int calculateRoomBooking(string RoomType, int nbNights, int nbPeople)
{

    int totalFareInt = 0;
    int dailyRateInt = 0;

    // set daily rate based on selected room type
    switch (RoomType)
    {
        case "Standard":
            dailyRateInt = 100;
            break;
        case "Superior":
            dailyRateInt = 150;
            break;
        case "Luxury":
            dailyRateInt = 175;
            break;
    }

   // calculation of booking rate
   totalFareInt = dailyRateInt * nbNights + 10 * (nbPeople - 1) * nbNights;
    // USING nbNights AND nbPeople instead of nbNightsInt and nbPeopleInt

   // display booking rate
   totalRateTextBox.Text = totalFareInt.ToString();
   return 1;     //Change 1 to the value which you want to return from the function.
}
```

Comment: yes but you're not providing him what he needed to do...

Comment: @NoIdeaForName:- I think OP is not clear with the idea of Scope of the variables. Although I have updated my answer. Hope that makes him get what he wants!!!!

Comment: i think he just wanted to use the function parameters.... please take a look at the signature of the function and the way he uses it

Comment: @NoIdeaForName:- Got your point.!! :)

Comment: Hi, thanks but when i write the code, it said: calculateRoomBooking (not all code paths return a value) ??

Comment: Because you have to specify the return value ;)

Comment: private int calculateRoomBooking(RoomType, nbNights, nbPeople)....like this??

Comment: I have updated the answer. Hope that works for you!!!

Comment: thanks....but what do you mean by "Return 1"?

Comment: return 1 is simply the return type of your method. I have just returned 1 in this case. You may change that as per your requirement. P.S. Does my answer helped you???

Answer (score 1):

you've mistakenly tried to use `nbNightsInt` and `nbPeopleInt` when the function parameters are `nbNights` and `nbPeople`

do:

```
private int calculateRoomBooking(string RoomType, int nbNights, int nbPeople)
{

    int totalFareInt = 0;
    int dailyRateInt = 0;

    // set daily rate based on selected room type
    switch (RoomType)
    {
        case "Standard":
            dailyRateInt = 100;
            break;
        case "Superior":
            dailyRateInt = 150;
            break;
        case "Luxury":
            dailyRateInt = 175;
            break;
    }

   // calculation of booking rate
   totalFareInt = dailyRateInt * nbNights + 10 * (nbPeople - 1) * nbNights;
    // USING nbNights AND nbPeople instead of nbNightsInt and nbPeopleInt

   // display booking rate
   totalRateTextBox.Text = totalFareInt.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Just to add to what No Idea For Name correctly wrote that it seems that when you call `calculateRoomBooking` in `calculateRateButton_Click` you are having `nbPeopleInt` passed as `nbNights` and then used as such. So please make sure you rearrange your arguments in your call of `calculateRoomBooking`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the variables 'nbNightsInt' and 'nbPeopleInt' instead of 'nbNights' and 'nbPeople', and those 2 don't exist in that scope. Just change the variable names on that line:

```
totalFareInt = dailyRateInt * nbNights + 10 * (nbPeople - 1) * nbNights;
```